# How to access the ubuntu installed in oracle virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, oracle, shared-folders

I have Ubuntu installed in an Oracle Virtualbox machine. The host machine is a Windows 10 installation.

How can I access the files of the client machine (Ubuntu) from the host machine?

I can access the shared folder in computer1 from computer2 (by way of smb://IP/folder).
However, I cannot do the reverse following the same procedure.

Comment: A good start to any question is what version of Ubuntu are you using? Please show the commands you have tried by EDITing the question and add them.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a network

You first need to create a network in order for the host machine and VM to communicate:
In Virtualbox, go to File -> Preferences. Switch to the network section on the left and go to the Host-Only Networks tab. Use the `+` icon to create a new network.

You can configure this as you see best, but it would be a good idea to configure a static IP, for easier connection later on. This answer assumes you used a static IP.

## Configure a network adapter

### VM to host adapter

Turn on the checkbox `Enable Network Adapter` in the network tab of the settings to create a network adapter. `Attached To` should be `Host-Only adapter` In the `Name` dropdown, choose the name of the network you created earlier.

### Host to Internet adapter

Add a second network card by switching to the `Adapter 2`  tab. It should be attached to `NAT` which connects this network card to the internet.

## Setup static IP on the VM

In the guest machine, you'll need to configure the static IP. Run: `ip add` which shows the three interfaces `lo` (loopback), `enp0s3` (adapter 1) `enp0s8` (adapter 2).

Copy these settings into `/etc/network/interfaces` to set a static IP for your server. You can change these as required.

```
auto  enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address  192.168.56.5
network  192.168.56.0
netmask  255.255.255.0
gateway  192.168.56.1
dns-nameservers  8.8.8.8  192.168.56.1
```

Ensure the `enp0s3` IP is the same as the static IP you configured above. (If it isn't, reboot and try again.)

Restart networking (`sudo systemctl restart networking`) or reboot to save changes.

## Finished

You can now use ssh, ftp, or whatever other file transfer service you prefer to connect from the host machine to the guest, using the IP you configured above.